# How to pass data from a class to a stateful page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

so I have a class named planets

```
class Planets {
          final String cover;
        
          Planets({
            this.cover,
          });
        }
        List<Planets> recentList = [
          Planets(
          cover:
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Planets2013.svg/260px-Planets2013.svg.png"
          ),
    ];
```

and I want to call the "cover value" from the planets class into my MyHomePage stateful widget class

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
```

and use it as an image such as

```
    Image.network(planets.cover,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        height: 200,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      ),
```

how would I be able to use it?

Answer (score 0):

you should call recentlist in the `Image.network`

```
Image.network(recentList[0].cover,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: 200,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              )
```

Comment: this works, but im more spesifically looking to call it by Using more like Planets.cover, how would i do that?

Comment: please mark the solution as correct if it works for you @LaurenTsai

Comment: but this is not what im looking for

Comment: `recentList[0].cover` represents Planets.cover because recentList[0] is an object of Planets and this is the actual way of represent the `Planet` class.

Comment: @LaurenTsai do you understand?